# How to get the current date time in plsql?

Tags: oracle, plsql

My Code:

```
DECLARE

BEGIN 

    -- outputs 06-DEC-18
    dbms_output.put_line(sysdate);  

    -- also outputs 18-DEC-06
    dbms_output.put_line(to_date(sysdate,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')); 
END;
/
```

The output only shows the date. I want to get also the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SYSDATE` does have a time component. The first one **outputs** `06-DEC-18` because your session's parameter `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is set to `DD-MON-YY`.

You have these options.

use `TO_CHAR`

```
dbms_output.put_line(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'));
```

Modify `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` to show time.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss';
BEGIN
   dbms_output.put_line(SYSDATE); 
END;
/
```

Or use `SYSTIMESTAMP` to show higher precision of time like milliseconds.

```
BEGIN 
    dbms_output.put_line(SYSTIMESTAMP); 
END;
/
```

Comment: @ktaro : One other thing I forgot to add in the answer : you should never use `to_date` on a date as in your second attempt `to_date(sysdate,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')`. That leads to implicit conversion of dates and sometimes gives incorrect results or error.

Comment: Yeah.When I used `to_date` on a date, I have already a feeling that there's wrong with it, because sysdate is already a date.Now I know that this is a bad practice. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use SYSTIMESTAMP

```
SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP
FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert date type to string with some format use [to_char](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html)

```
to_char(sysdate::timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: Casting using `::` doesn't work in Oracle and there's no need to  cast it to timestamp.